# Who was Abraham’s Mother?

Tags: abraham, genealogy, matrilineal-descent

I was wondering if we have any info/ sources on who Abrahams’s mother was?

It seems interesting that she was never mentioned, and doesn’t play any role in his story, or his leaving his “father’s house”

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%99_%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%95

Answer (score 6):

Refer to [Bava Basra 91a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.91a.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> וְאָמַר רַב חָנָן בַּר רָבָא אָמַר רַב אִמֵּיהּ דְּאַבְרָהָם אֲמַּתְלַאי בַּת כַּרְנְבוֹ אִמֵּיהּ דְּהָמָן אֲמַּתְלַאי בַּת עוֹרֶבְתִּי וְסִימָנָיךְ טָמֵא טָמֵא טָהוֹר טָהוֹר
>
> And Rav Chanan bar Rava says that Rav says: The mother of Avraham was called Amaslai bas Karnevo. The mother of Haman was called Amaslai bas Orevti. And your mnemonic, to ensure that the two are not confused for one another, is that a raven [orev] is impure, and in this manner one remembers that Orevti is the grandmother of the impure Haman, while a sheep [kar] is pure, which indicates that Karnevo is the grandmother of the pure Avraham.

Answer (score 3):

Besides for the Talmudic tradition brought by @Dov, there are two other traditions:

1. [Jubilees 11:22-23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Book_of_Jubilees.11.22-23?vhe=Book_of_Jubilees,_Vienna_1870,_Wikisource&lang=bi) - Edna bat Aram
2. [Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer 26:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.26.3?vhe=Pirkei_Derabi_Eliezer&lang=bi) - Atedai

Answer (score 1):

See also [Sefer HaYashar](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaYashar_(midrash)%2C_Book_of_Genesis%2C_Noach.8?vhe=Sefer_HaYashar,_Livorno_1870&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> And Terah took unto himself a wife ‎and her name was Amthelah the daughter of Carnebah, and she conceived and bare a son in ‎those days. And Terah was seventy years old when she bare him, and Terah called the name ‎of the son born unto him Abram, saying: In these days the king has raised and exalted me over ‎all the princes that are with him.

And [Midbar Kedemot (letter Tav)](https://www.sefaria.org/Midbar_Kedemot%2C_Letter_Tav.27?vhe=Livorno_1792&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), written by the Chida.

Answer (score 1):

Although not related directly to the question, which has already been answered correctly, I've seen quoted from the Maharam Mipano (haven't found the source yet) a fascinating comment. He writes that the mother whose 7 sons were killed because they refused to bow down to an idol,(https://www.sefaria.org.il/Gittin.57b.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)
was the reincarnation of Avraham's mother. She had apparently tried (7 times?) to persuade her son Avraham to save his life by bowing down to Nimrod's idol. By having brought up 7 sons who refused to bow down to an idol, she received her Tikkun. He explains that this is why, after the death of her last son, she said אָמְרָה לוֹ בָּנַיי לְכוּ וְאִמְרוּ לְאַבְרָהָם אֲבִיכֶם אַתָּה עָקַדְתָּ מִזְבֵּחַ אֶחָד וַאֲנִי עָקַדְתִּי שִׁבְעָה מִזְבְּחוֹת - *She said to him: My son, go and say to your father Abraham, You bound one son to the altar, but I bound seven altars* as per גיטין נז ע"ב

Comment: Very interesting, would love to see any sources you can find here.